# Difference between Cartesian products with and without Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory

With Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs $(a, b)$, then my understanding is that the Cartesian product of sets $A = \{a, b\}$ and $B=\{x, y\}$ becomes:

$$
\begin{align}
A\times B&=\{(a, x), (a, y), (b, x), (b, y)\}
\\&=\{\{\{a\}, \{a, x\}\}, \{\{a\}, \{a, y\}\}, \{\{b\}, \{b, x\}\},\{\{b\}, \{b, y\}\}\}.
\end{align}
$$

While without Kuratowski's definition, it is:

$$
\begin{align}
A\times B&=\{(a, x), (a, y), (b, x), (b, y)\}.
\end{align}
$$

So there's a difference in the resultant Cartesian products between the two definitions.

Is that correct and if so how can we know which definition is being used with the notation $X\times Y$?

Comment: Your first and second results are the same, except in the first result you have expanded out the definition of ordered pair (incorrectly as $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ ). As long as you are consistent with a viable definition of ordered pair, I think it will be ok.

Comment: @Porky I don't quite get what it means by "...incorrectly as $(a, b)=\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$", isn't that Kuratowski's definition of an ordered pair?

Comment: where does the {a} come from? (a,b) is {{a},{a,b}} not {a},{a,b}, that's what @Porky is getting at. Look again at what you wrote, are you expanding out the ordered pair properly? Think of it this way, by your notation, you are claiming {a} is an element of A cross B, is that possible?

Comment: @MichaelCarey right, I've absolutely missed some braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My requirments for ordered pairs:

- for any $a$, $b$, we have an ordered pair $(a,b)$.
- for an ordered pair $\alpha$, we have an algorithm to get back $\mathrm{pr}_1(\alpha)$ and $\mathrm{pr}_2(\alpha)$ so that $\alpha = (\mathrm{pr}_1(\alpha), \mathrm{pr}_2(\alpha))$.
- $(a,b) = (c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$, $b=d$.

As long as these conditions are satisfied, I can use any definition of ordered pairs. The definition $(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{\{a,b\}\}$ is good only because it is a set ($a$ and $b$ would be also sets here).

Comment: Yes, other definitions are workable as well (e.g. the first viable definition was made by Norbert Weiner in 1914, with $<a,b>$ defined as $\{\{\{a\},ϕ\},\{\{b\}\}\}$). Interestingly some theorems use the definition (e.g. that $A$x$B$ is a set). I guess they could be shown to be true under any definition that satisfy your criteria.